# Word-selection swapping

Tags: vim

I have found in vim.wikia a very useful tip (Tip 47) which suggests a visual-mode swapping.

> To use this mapping: first, delete some text (using a command such as
>   daw or dt in normal mode, or x in visual mode). Then, use visual mode
>   to select some other text, and press Ctrl-X. The two pieces of text
>   should then be swapped.

```
:vnoremap <C-X> <Esc>`.``gvP``P
```

I did as indicated, and it worked fine, except for one glitch (very minor, I must admit) : if I want to swap the two following texts :

```
[some text not to be swapped] London and Barcelona
...
[some other text not to be swapped] New York and Buenos Aires
```

I end up with :

```
[some text not to be swapped]New York and Buenos Aires
...
[some other text not to be swapped] London and Barcelona
```

There is no space between ] and New York.

This is probably due to the fact that I do not fully understand (to say the least) the above :vnoremap, and do not know how to insert a space in it.

Your help (and explanation) would be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the `P` at the end pasting *before* the cursor: because the cursor is on a space, pasting pushes it to the end of the line (yes, you should have a trailing space, now).

Using `p` would fix your mapping for this specific use case ,"text at the end of the line", but it would mess with what I guess was the general case for which that mapping was created, "text somewhere in the line".

*edit*

This quick and dirty function checks if the cursor is at the end of the line before deciding if it does `p` or `P` but… you might as well use one of the plugins listed in that tip.

```
function! Swap()
    normal `.``gvP``
    if col('.') == len(getline('.'))
        normal p
    else
        normal P
    endif
endfunction

xnoremap <F7> <Esc>:call Swap()<CR>
```

Comment: 1) sorry for this tardy reply : I did not expect an answer so soon... 2) your solution works perfectly for my needs. Thank you very much.

Comment: Vim-related questions usually have a bunch of valid answers in an hour or two, here, thanks to a small but active community.

Comment: This time I answer speedily : it boils down to another question : how to delete, e.g. 3 words without the trailing (i.e. the third) space ? I only found one clumsy way : d/<space><first letter of the 4th word>. Anyway, I shall keep your "quick and dirty" solution ...

Comment: `viwEEd` would be one way, `d3E` (or `bd3E` if the cursor is not on the first letter of the first word) would be another way, `d3t<space>` (or `bd3t<space>`) would be yet another way.

Comment: Thanks to you, my initial question made me learn quite a few things... Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind installing a plugin, there are several that provide this and more: My [SwapText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4971) among them. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I shall definitely give it a try.